# Cross domain ajax request issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, jsonp

I need to get the json data from the cross domain.

```
$.getJSON('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/SampleService/Handler.ashx?callback=?', data, function (jsonData) {
                alert('1');
            })
            .done(function () { console.log("second success"); })
            .fail(function () { console.log("error"); })
            .always(function () { console.log("complete"); });
```

Handler code:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                SampleService service = new SampleService();

                List<List<Byte>> response = service.GetData();
                string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
                context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0}([{1}]);", context.Request["callback"], jsonData));
```

The error, I'm getting is:

```
"parsererror"
Error: jQuery19108131180874027861_1366004862133 was not called
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonp calls for Cross Domain requests. Use something like this

```
$.ajax({
        url : "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/SampleService/Handler.ashx",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp : "callback",
        success: function(data) {alert("Success");},
        error: function(data) { alert("Error"); }

        });        
   });
```

on your php page return result like this

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . "($result)";exit;
```

where $result is your json_encoded array.

Comment: @chandresh you have a trailing `,` at the end of error function. This can cause issues in IE browsers.

Comment: you need to provide the `callback` function when request finishes `ajax` will call this function there u do what u want

Comment: @Jai valid point have edited the question. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @dianuj does my updated answer make point to what you illustrated?

Comment: `asp.net` not `php` try answering in that context.

Comment: @chandresh_cool yes your answer points the solution for the above question i want to address benjamin54

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery19108131180874027861_1366004862133 you are seeing is an auto generated callback wrapper function which jQuery attaches when you don't specify a callback function. ie you have callback=?. If you have access to the server side script which you are calling you can wrap your JSON in a function and call that using JSONP to get around the cross domain issue. Ie - name your callback function jsonCallback.

Server side script output:

```
jsonCallback(
    {
        [insert your json code here]
    }
);
```

Then client side:

(function($) {
var url = 'http://www.jquery4u.com/scripts/jquery4u-sites.json?callback=?';

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    done: function(json) {
       console.dir(json);
    },
    fail: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Further reading: [JQUERY’S JSONP EXPLAINED WITH EXAMPLES](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/)

Comment: You can add `crossdomain: true,` too.

Comment: Also note that function .success() and error() are deprecated since jQuery 1.9.x for .done() and .fail().

Comment: @SamDeeringjquery4u.com, after using your code, it didn't reached neither `done` or `fail` section. Also I got empty response(in Firebug's Net tab)