# $http.delete returns error without information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have a weird problem with AngularJS and a REST webservice.
This is my code:

```
$http.delete(appSettings['baseUrl'] + 'pricelistitem/' + article.itemNumber + '/' + article.acc)
                    .error(function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
```

When calling this, I'm getting an error and the `.error` is executed, but the `e` object is `null`.

In the console, I'm getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When doing the DELETE request in postman (the same one which gets called by my code), I'm getting these headers in the reponse:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Content-Length → 2
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Fri, 29 May 2015 06:26:00 GMT
X-Powered-By → IBM i
```

I would say these headers are correct and I shouldn't get this error. Even if I did, the error object is null and so showing me no information at all.

UPDATE 15/06:
This issue occurs both when attempting to use PUT and DELETE. POST and GET works fine. In the network tab of Chrome dev tools, I can only see an OPTIONS request. In this request, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is NOT present (but it is in the PUT/DELETE when testing this in Postman), even after configuring the Apache configuration to include this header in every response.

I've been working for hours on this problem without any result.

What could be causing this problem? Does the OPTIONS request also need to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Only requests initiated by scripts are affected by CORS. Therefore testing a DELETE request in Postman is completely useless if you are facing a problem related to CORS. You would have to simulate the preflight request. Take the error message seriously and ask yourself why the server wouldn't send an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

Comment: Well, I honestly have no clue. The server returns that header, no matter if an error occurs or not..

Comment: The first possible problem is that the server doesn't add that header on `OPTIONS` requests. Another reason could be that the header is either not added on requests from `localhost` or it's only added on requests from certain hosts. Try sending an `OPTIONS` request using Postman including the header `Origin: http://localhost:5000`.

Comment: does `appSettings['baseUrl']` point to your own domain? Have you done a `console.log(appSettings['baseUrl'])` or some other way confirmed it returns a value?

Comment: Yes, that works absolutely fine. I use that constant everywhere in the project and the console reports the correct URL is called.

Comment: Of course, the `Access-Control-` headers have to be present in the response to an `OPTIONS` request. That's what I've written a month ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

You are facing [Cross Domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem and what you should do is enabling `CORS` from your server side.

Comment: i think cors is enabled, as we can see on headers output

Comment: This has been enabled by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. This headers does the trick (although I know this is not recommended in production) with other parts of the WS, but not with this one for some reason..

Comment: how you add headers in your server side?

Comment: These headers were added in the code, which is written in RPG by a back-end programmer running on a AS/400 system. I don't have any knowledge about that, but does it matter? After all, they are included in the response, right?

Comment: From what you provide these headers work with Get, POST or PUT, right? If so, DELETE should work either in Angular. AFAIK, we need to some trick in IIS sometimes when developing ASP.NET. I just want to figure out whether it can be a backend issue.

Comment: Yup, a DELETE should normally work. I was thinking Angular can't work with the status code 200 in a DELETE (which it now returns), although 200 is a correct status code to return. If I look at the network log in Chrome, I can see only an OPTION request is called, not the actually DELETE request.

Comment: Have you ever tried to send cors request using JQuery? If it fails in jquery either, then you should report this issue to your backend pair.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet, but I'll do that soon. If it works in JQuery but not in Angular, isn't it an Angular issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79090/discussion-between-rebornix-and-bv202).

Answer (score 0):

[What is cros issue and how to solve it](http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/)

From client side you have to set these value some time or try  [Chrome cross plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)  for testing to check whether it is cross domain error or other issue

or try this $httpProvider

and see this link [Enabling CORS in Angular JS](http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/)

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, accept, content-type' };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST' };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'dataType': 'jsonp' };
```

Comment: Where should I add this code and why do I need it? Yes, when using a plugin to avoid CORS errors, it works fine.

Comment: see this link http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/ AND ajax cros issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008324/cross-domain-ajax-request-issue

Comment: @Bv202 first try chrome app it will clear your doubt it is cros issue or other issue if it works then you have to set this above value which is mentioned in answer